# Not sure How to fix this issues about FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL

Tags: php, email

Please check my code. I have to 2 fields for validate email

**one is**

```
if ($email == NULL) {
            $error['email'] = "email is missing";
        }
```

**another is**

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error['emailfilter'] = "email is Invalid";
    }
```

But my Problem is when email field is blank/empty. I found those 2 warring is show. "email is missing" &  "email is Invalid"; I want only one warring will show. Such as if email filed is blank/empty. It will show only "email is missing" not show me "email is Invalid" and when email is not valid It will show "email is Invalid". Below is my full code.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['contact'])) {

        $warning = array();
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $msg = $_POST['message'];
        $to = "asifurrahaman124@gmail.com";
        $sub = "you got a msg";
        $headers = "from: $email";

        if ($firstname == NULL) {
            $error['fname'] = "firstname is missing";
        }
        if($lastname == NULL){
            $error['lname'] = "Last name is missing";
        }
        if ($email == NULL) {
            $error['email'] = "email is missing";
        }

        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error['emailfilter'] = "email is Invalid";
        }

        if ($msg == NULL) {
            $error['msg'] = "message is required";
        }
        if (count( $error ) == 0) {
            mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers);

            $success = "Message Submited";
        }
    }


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>conatact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" Placeholder="First Name"><br />
        <p class="error"><?php if (isset($error['fname'])) {
            echo $error['fname'];
        }?></p>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" Placeholder="Last Name"><br />
        <p class="error"><?php if (isset($error['lname'])) {
            echo $error['lname'];
        }?></p>
        <input type="email" name="email" Placeholder="Email"><br />
        <p class="error"><?php if (isset($error['email'])) {
            echo $error['email'];
        }?></p>
        <p class="error"><?php if (isset($error['emailfilter'])) {
            echo $error['emailfilter'];
        }?></p>
        <textarea name="message"  cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br />
        <p class="error"><?php if (isset($error['msg'])) {
            echo $error['msg'];
        }?></p>

        <input type="password" name="password" Placeholder="Password"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="send" name="contact">

    </form>
    <h2 class="error"><?php if (isset($success)) {
            echo $success;
        }?></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [elseif](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)?

Comment: Why don't you use a validation library ? vlucas/valitron is a decent one

Comment: For your own and others' security, please read up about correct handling of user input. A place to start is [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp).

Comment: Bit of a side note here; use ajax/jquery for this. I'd find it quite annoying having to reload/retype everything back in again where I'd of probably missed a field or two that I felt I didn't want to fill in.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will use Ajax/jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) for this, it will only trigger if the first condition isn't matched.

```
if ($email == NULL) {
    $error['email'] = "email is missing";
} elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error['emailfilter'] = "email is Invalid";
}
```

This will check the first condition, do they have an email, if not it'll populate `$error['email']`, if the email has a value then it'll perform the `filter_var` on the email to check it's validity.